# npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE is being displayed while running "npn start" on window command line for the following package.json file

Tags: package.json

I am learning full stack web development with Angular and new to web deployment.I am unable to guess the reason behind this  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE; displayed while running "npn start" on window command line for the following package.json file. I am stuck here and not much help available on google or I am unable to search right answer because of lack of proper keyword required to search the answer.

```
{
  "name": "confusion",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is a website for Ristorante Con Fusion",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "npm run watch:all",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "scss": "node-sass -o css/ css/",
    "watch:scss": "onchange \"css/*.scss\" -- npm run scss",
    "watch:all": "parallelshell \"npm run watch:scss\" \"npm run lite\""
  },
  "author": "Imtiaz",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "onchange": "^3.3.0",
    "parallelshell": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.0.0-alpha2",
    "bootstrap-social": "^5.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9"
  }
}
```

OutPut:

```
C:\Users\NEW WS-08\Bootstrap4\conFusion>npm start

> confusion@1.0.0 start C:\Users\NEW WS-08\Bootstrap4\conFusion
> npm run watch:all


> confusion@1.0.0 watch:all C:\Users\NEW WS-08\Bootstrap4\conFusion
> parallelshell "npm run watch:scss" "npm run lite"

child_process.js:422
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('options.cwd', 'string', options.cwd);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "options.cwd" property must be of type str
ing. Received type function
←[90m    at normalizeSpawnArguments (child_process.js:422:11)←[39m
←[90m    at spawn (child_process.js:534:16)←[39m
    at C:\Users\NEW WS-08\Bootstrap4\conFusion\node_modules\←[4mparallelshell←[2
4m\index.js:104:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\NEW WS-08\Bootstrap4\conFusion\node_modules\
←[4mparallelshell←[24m\index.js:100:6)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10
)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)←[39
m {
  code: ←[32m'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'←[39m
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! confusion@1.0.0 watch:all: `parallelshell "npm run watch:scss" "npm run
 lite"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the confusion@1.0.0 watch:all script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\NEW WS-08\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-26T08_26
_18_785Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! confusion@1.0.0 start: `npm run watch:all`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the confusion@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\NEW WS-08\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-26T08_26
_18_841Z-debug.log
```

Comment: did u manage to solve this issue?

Comment: yes, Its solved now

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue can not be fixed using npm audit fix. All you can do is to copy the actual index.js file of parallelshell into your node_modules directory.

So to do it below are the instructions:

1. Go to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/darkguy2008/parallelshell/master/index.js

2. Copy the content here.

3. Now go to the directory of your project, it may be something like /project/node_modules/parallelshell/index.js

4. Inside the index.js replace the contents with the one you copied from the link in Step 1.

5. Save the file and exit.

Hope this fix will work for you.